# Having multiple relations in edit/create form

Tags: forms, edit, relations

In my app user can create something called *Package*. Package has to have following

- *Model*
- *Books*(which in turn belong to Model. When selecting Model, user can also select multiple Books for Model)
- *Contact*

First thought was having *wizard*, i.e. having 3 steps:

1. Select Model
2. Select Books for each Model
3. Select Contacts

But afaik this doesn't work well if user can not only create an entity, but also edit it.

Is there some pattern or examples of how to manage this kind of complex relationships and dependent entities in a form?

Attached are mockups for current iteration I came up with. So far creation of Package is split in to two different screens. On one Models and Books are selected, and Contacts + additional data on another. But I don't really see how a user can easily edit data in this screen configuration, i.e. clicking on "Edit Package" in Package list will probably open first screen, and won't give full overview.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking.

Comment: What is the problem putting the contact section under the model/book section, in one view?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. Merge them into a single step.
2. Add nesting: Model->Book->Contact  (As shown in attachment)
3. Editing and Adding could be accomodated in the same page.

It is not clear from your question, what add/edit/show does, but I still have given a similar functionality as of my understanding.
But i hope you got my point; **Nesting the 3 entities with minimizable/maximizable elements would solve the problem.** :)